# Web API Exception Wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception, httpresponse

I'm using WebAPI to call some third party methods:

```
public class SessionsController : ApiController
{
    public DataTable Get(int id)
    {
        return Services.TryCall(es => es.GetSessionList(id).Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

I'm wrapping all calls on this services:

```
internal static class Services
{
    internal static IExternalService ExternalService { get; set; }

    internal static T TryCall<T>(Func<IExternalService,T> theFunction)
    {
        try
        {
            return theFunction(ExternalService);
        }
        catch (FaultException<MyFaultDetail> e)
        {
            var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
            message.Content = new StringContent(e.Detail.Message);
            throw new HttpResponseException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When an exception is thrown, it is caught and the message prepared. With rethrowing I get a new Error Message:

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

How can i return this exception properly, without Visual Studio complaining? When i skip the error, the browser gets an 501 error result.
The Method `Request.CreateResponse()` is not available in my wrapper method.

Comment: `Request.CreateResponse()` isn't available? You can make it available, right?

Comment: Afaik the extension methods are inherited from `ApiController` base class. So it's not in my Services class...

Comment: Pass the `Request` object into the `TryCall` method then?

Comment: I don't like the idea of passing the request on every call. Can i wrap it in my `TryCall` method anyhow?

Comment: You either pass it in or in get it in the method with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.request`

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.request` returns `null` in Services. I'll try to pass it in... still looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: @DanielR. Check my answer, this is what is reommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, while this may work, I recommend you creating an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` for this. This way, you won't have to guard every method for exception with the same bloated code.

For example:

```
    public class FaultExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is FaultException)
            {
                context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are several ways you can use this filter:

**1. By Action**

To apply the filter to a specific action, add the filter as an attribute to the action:

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [FaultExceptionFilter]
    public Contact SampleMethod(int id)
    {
       //Your call to a method throwing FaultException
        throw new FaultException<MyFaultDetail>("This method is not implemented");
    }
}
```

**2. By Controller:**

To apply the filter to all of the actions on a controller, add the filter as an attribute to the controller class:

```
[FaultExceptionFilter]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    // ...
}
```

**3. Globally**

To apply the filter globally to all Web API controllers, add an instance of the filter to the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters` collection. Exeption filters in this collection apply to any Web API controller action.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new FaultExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

If you use the "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" project template to create your project, put your Web API configuration code inside the `WebApiConfig` class, which is located in the `App_Start` folder:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new FaultExceptionFilterAttribute());

        // Other configuration code...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and then visual studio complains on the unhandled `ThrowFaultException` method.. same but different :/

Comment: @DanielR. Have you written something to the response in the Attribute? VS will throw an exception locally as you might be in debug mode. It will just return the response as given in the Attribute if configured properly.

Comment: If you are able to show what you have tried, we might be able to help

Comment: Ok the message seems to annoy me because of debug mode ^^ Nevermind then. I switched from my wrapper method to the `FaultExceptionFilter` as recommended ;) Thank you!